# How do I run a website in bitnami+docker+nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, bitnami

I'm taking over a website https://www.funfun.io. Unfortunately, I cannot reach the previous developer anymore.

This is a AngularJS+Node+Express+MongoDB application. He decided to use bitnami+docker+nginx in the server. Here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  funfun-node:
    image: funfun
    restart: always
    build: .
    environment:
    - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/news
    env_file:
    - ./.env
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
  funfun-nginx:
    image: funfun-nginx
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    ports:
    - "3000:8443"
    depends_on:
    - funfun-node
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - "10studio-mongo:/data/db"
    ports:
    - "27018:27017"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: 10studio
volumes:
  10studio-mongo:
    driver: local
```

`Dockerfile.nginx`:

```
FROM bitnami/nginx:1.16
COPY ./funfun.io /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/default.conf
COPY ./ssl/MyCompanyLocalhost.cer /opt/MyCompanyLocalhost.cer
COPY ./ssl/MyCompanyLocalhost.pvk /opt/MyCompanyLocalhost.pvk
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12
RUN npm install -g yarn nrm --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org && nrm use cnpm
COPY ./package.json /opt/funfun/package.json
WORKDIR /opt/funfun
RUN yarn
COPY ./ /opt/funfun/
CMD yarn start
```

In my local machine, I could use `npm start` to test the website in a web browser.

I have access to the Ubuntu server. But I'm new to bitnami+docker+nginx, I have the following questions:

1. In the command line of Ubuntu server, how could I check if the service is running (besides launching the website in a browser)?
2. How could I shut down and restart the service?
3. Previously, without docker, we could start mongodb by `sudo systemctl enable mongod`. Now, with docker, how could we start mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

- `docker-compose ps` will give you the state of your containers

2.

- `docker-compose stop` will stop your containers, keeping their state then you may start them as their are using `docker-compose up`
- `docker-compose kill` will delete your containers
- `docker-compose restart` will restart your containers

3.

- By declaring your mongodb using an official mongo image your container start when you do `docker-compose up` without any other intervention.
- Or you can add `command: mongod --auth` directly into your docker-compose.yml

the official documentation of docker is very detailed and help a lot for all of this, keep looking on it https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Thank you... Additionally, if it was a React application, should we build static files in the server, or build static files on our local machine and copy them to the server by `scp`?

Comment: Always do server way, so that your are sure it work on your server (and not on your computer only). build on your server ensurce that all requierements are present

Comment: We use GitHub to store our code, additionally he has that `Dockerfile`. In your opinion, what should be the process to update the server side if I modify some code locally?

Comment: IT depends on your CI you're using, follow what does you CI

Comment: What does "CI" mean?

Comment: Continus integration

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to deploy the services mentioned in the compose file locally, you should run the below command

```
docker-compose up
docker-compose up -d # in the background
```

After running the above command docker containers will be created and available on your machine.

To list the running containers

```
docker ps
docker-compose ps
```

To stop containers

```
docker stop ${container name}
docker-compose stop
```

mongodb is part of the docker-compose file and it will be running once you start other services. It will also be restarted automatically in case it crashes or you restarted your machine.

One final note, since you are using external networks you may need to create the network before starting the services.

Comment: Thank you... Additionally, if it was a React application, should we build static files in the server, or build static files on our local machine and copy them to the server by `scp`?

Comment: The easiest way to solve this issue is to build static files during building the docker image. You need to update the docker image for the node application to build the assets. Here is an article that explains how to do this for sharing the assets between backend applications and Nginx  (it is not the exact case but it is helful) https://medium.com/faun/three-methods-to-share-rails-assets-with-nginx-f39c90bb7d68